# unable to run C:\composer\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Here is the result of `symfony check:requirements`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP_7_2_6\ext\openssl' - Le module spÚcifiÚ est introuvable.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP_7_2_6\ext\openssl' - Le module spÚcifiÚ est introuvable.
 in Unknown on line 0

Symfony Requirements Checker
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
C:\PHP_7_2_6\php.ini

> Checking Symfony requirements:

...........W..WWW........W


 [OK]
 Your system is ready to run Symfony projects 


Optional recommendations to improve your setup
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 some recommendations.........
```

Then I execute `symfony new --webapp projet I get

```
* Creating a new Symfony project with Composer
  (running C:\composer\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton C:\Users\Esref\Documents\ProjetCo\website  --no-interaction)


Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP_7_2_6\ext\openssl' - Le module sp�cifi� est introuvable.
 in Unknown on line 0
Composer 2.3.0 dropped support for PHP <7.2.5 and you are running 5.6.40, please upgrade PHP or use Composer 2.2 LTS via "composer self-update --2.2". Aborting.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP_7_2_6\ext\openssl' - Le module sp�cifi� est introuvable.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Of course, the openssl is activated in my php.ini that you can see here
https://pasteio.com/raw/xXhrAVH2bJxj

Comment: Well looks like your version of composer does not work with your version of PHP. Either upgrade PHP or downgrade composer. I would recommend to upgrade PHP. Plus you are missing an OpenSSL extension but that is not the problem here.

Comment: I don't know who closed this question but it is not a duplicate of that previous question. The problem here is an incompatibility between the PHP and the composer versions.

Comment: Yeah, I forget that I had other versions of PHP installed (WAMPserver). I deleted these versions, and problem solved. Thanks